# TokBox subscriber snapshot on Web

Tags: javascript, webrtc, opentok, tokbox

i am trying to capture snapshot of subscriber in my web application.

I want to capture snapshot on click of a button.

```
    var imgData = subscriber.getImgData();
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("src", "data:image/png;base64," + imgData);

    // Replace with the parent DIV for the img
    document.getElementById("containerId").appendChild(img);
```

This is the code which they have provide in there developer file. without any description on how to implement it.

now my problem is, if i put it in button onClick function like

```
    function capture(){

    }
```

it will not do anything because there is no possible way to get subscriber value on capture() function.

Subscriber has already been initiated when joining a session in different function ex below

```
    function initializeSession() {
          var session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId);
          session.on('streamCreated', function streamCreated(event) {
                var subscriberOptions = {
                      insertMode: 'append',
                      width: '100%',
                      height: '100%'
                 };
           var subscriber = session.subscribe(event.stream, 'subscribers', subscriberOptions, handleError);

                });
```

If anyone can help me on this, how do i capture snapshot on button click. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

OpenTok Developer Advocate here.

You'd want to modify your code to define the subscriber object outside the `initializeSession` function, like so:

```
var subscriber;
function initializeSession() {
  var session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId);
  session.on('streamCreated', function streamCreated(event) {
    var subscriberOptions = {
      insertMode: 'append',
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%'
    };
    subscriber = session.subscribe(event.stream, 'subscribers', subscriberOptions, handleError);
  });
}
```

Then you can access the `subscriber` object within your `capture` function like so:

```
function capture(){
  if (subscriber) {
    var imgData = subscriber.getImgData();
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("src", "data:image/png;base64," + imgData);

    // Replace with the parent DIV for the img
    document.getElementById("containerId").appendChild(img);
  }
}
```